# Can 2 .htaccess files block URL rewriting

Tags: php, codeigniter, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a codeigniter project inside the b1 folder in my public_html folder:

```
mydomain.com/b1/controller/function
```

I want to change it to:

```
mydomain.com/controller/function
```

in the browser bar using a 301 redirect.

My .htaccess file in my public_html has:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^b1/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ b1/$1

EXPLANATION:

RewriteRule ^b1/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC] # THIS IS TO REWRITE ALL REQUESTS FROM THE NAVBAR IN MY PROJECT WHICH HAVE THE FORM mydomain.com/b1/controller/function TO mydomain.com/controller/function. AFTER THIS THE NAVBAR SHOULD SHOW mydomain.com/controller/function ( I ASSUME )

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ b1/$1 # THIS IS TO TAKE ALL INCOMING REQUESTS AND ADD A b1 IN FRONT SO  mydomain.com/controller/function IS REDIRECTED TO  mydomain.com/b1/controller/function - BUT INTERNALLY, SO THAT THE BROWSERS ADDRESS BAR STILL SHOWS A 'PRETTIER'  mydomain.com/controller/function
```

According to http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/, this should work, but I still see:

```
mydomain.com/b1/controller/function
```

in my address bar.

Please note that this is a codeigniter project and  CI has the following .htaccess file . ( again the project is in my public_html/b1 directory )

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

As far as I can tell mod_rewrite is working because RewriteRule ^(.*)$ b1/$1 works when a match to the rule above it does not occur.

Could some combination of the 2 .htaccess files be causing the lack of visible rerwrite in the address bar? I would like to debug this and figure out how to achieve the URL format discussed above.

Thank you,

Bill

addendum: thanks to everybody for their attempts. what I notice about multiple answers though is that:

```
RewriteRule ^b1/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ b1/$1 [L]
```

Their seem to be a lot of L flags . In pseudocode what I want to achieve is:

```
IF REQUEST is mydomain.com or www.mydomain.com ( with nothing after the /) rewrite to mydomain.com . FIRST REWRITE TO REMOVE B1 IF EXISTS ( this is for the navbar requests which have form: mydomain.com/b1/controller/function which should be rewritten to mydomain.com/controller/function ) so that the address bar shows mydomain.com/controller/function
```

if theres an L above , I don't think it will work

```
Then add b1 back in internally so you redirect to b1 folder where project is stored
```

Comment: Put `RewriteOptions inherit` in the top of the lower level `.htaccess` file.

Comment: this causes a 500 server error

Comment: Hazarding a guess: `RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]`, the `L` means: do not process any further rules (and the 'deeper' .htaccess runs before the one in you document root). Could you try without that `L`?

Comment: I removed the L - No change

Comment: @crypticツ `RewriteOptions inherit` will not work according to [this link](http://fragmentsofcode.wordpress.com/2008/12/15/apache-gotcha-rewriteoptions-inherit/) since the rules will be placed after the current rules. So the catch all from codeigniter will prevent any further processing

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with the two `.htaccess` files your are using. When using `.htaccess` it will use the file that is closest to the requested folder. In your case you have the following folder structure

```
- public_html
  - B1
    - .htaccess  //from codeigniter project
  .htaccess //your own with redirect
```

So when you call the url `mydomain.com/b1/controller/function` the closest `.htaccess` it can find is the codeigniter one, so it will use this one. Your own file will not be used. In other words your redirect rules are never even evaluated.

Now if you call `mydomain.com/controller/function` the closest `.htaccess`, is your own and the request is redirected to `mydomain.com/b1/controller/function` as expected. There it will again try to find the closest `.htaccess` which is the codeigniter one and thus the request works.

There are two things you can do. The first and best thing is to remove your `.htaccess` and copy all files and folders from the `b1` folder back to your `public_html` folder and then simply remove the `b1` folder. This way your server doesnt even have a `b1` folder and everything will work as expected.

The second option would be to combine the two `.htaccess` files and keep them in your `public_html` folder. Make sure you delete the one in the `b1` folder. The file would look something like

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^b1/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ b1/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: For several reasons, I think your second option is what I want to pursue. I removed the CI .htacess file and added yours in, but its now showing me a directory for public_html

Comment: updated the last line. Could be your server requires a / before the last b1, incase it still does not work

Comment: I tried your new updated version with thelast rewrite rule as both RewriteRule ^(.*)$ b1/index.php/$1 [L] and RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /b1/index.php/$1 [L]. In both cases I just see a directory of mydomain.com

Comment: I didn't solve it , but I think you did the most to push this forward. Thank you - Regards - Bill

Answer (score 1):

My attempt:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^b1/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ b1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: this passes the domain name mydomain.com to the mydomain.com/b1 folder just fine but the requests generated by the codeigniter Navbar in form mydomain.com/b1/controller/function are not rewritten to mydomain.com/controller/function. I have replaced the CI .htacess file should I take it out?

Comment: Weird. Try removing the `PT` flag.

Comment: what PT flag? I don't see it above. Also again  I have replaced the CI .htacess file should I take it out, i.e. 1 htacess file or 2 ?

Comment: I meant the PT flag in the htaccess that is in the b1 folder.

Comment: So I am assuming you want to leave the CI .htacess file in place - I have done this and also took out the PT flag , no change. 2 additional points: 1) I just found out that my shared host provider uses a lightspeed server, not apache , although they tell me it uses the same htaccess lingo. 2) I added a line of giberish to the CI htacess file - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046908/testing-to-see-if-htacess-file-is-accessed. This does not cause server errors, so perhaps its not being accessed?

Comment: Sorry. If it's not apache, then it could be anything that's causing this.

Answer (score 0):

For 301 redirect use **Redirect** in .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 /redirect_from http://www.mydomain.com/redirect_to
```

Comment: mixkorshun, does this approach have a regex component? I need that

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using it in a b1 sub-folder when you want it to function as a main project in a domain ?

Comment: Furqan, 2 reasons: 1) I've read that its better to have your project outside the public_html directory for security reasons , so I put my project outside and symlink it to the b1 folder. 2) My main project is in b1 but I have other add on domains that have their own folders in the public_html directory

Comment: I see, then you must be using different domains, in this case you can use hostin feature addon domain which points to the given folder

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve what you're trying to do would be to move Codeigniter's `index.php` file into your `public_html/` folder and update the `$system_folder` and `$application_folder` paths to point to your `b1/` folder. Example below:

**`/public_html/index.php`**

```
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * SYSTEM FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * This variable must contain the name of your "system" folder.
 * Include the path if the folder is not in the same  directory
 * as this file.
 *
 */
$system_path = 'b1/system';

/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION FOLDER NAME
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * If you want this front controller to use a different "application"
 * folder then the default one you can set its name here. The folder
 * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server.  If
 * you do, use a full server path. For more info please see the user guide:
 * http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html
 *
 * NO TRAILING SLASH!
 *
 */
$application_folder = 'b1/application';
```

This will 'internally' tell Codeigniter that all your application stuff is in the `b1/` folder, but from an end-user perspective your domains will still look like `mydomain.com/controller/function`

Your `.htaccess` file will then look like this:

**`/public_html/.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# redirect any actual requests for your b1 folder
# back to the web root
RewriteRule ^b1/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]

# remove index.php from the url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

You shouldn't then have any need for a `.htaccess` file in the `b1` folder.

Comment: I actually tried this , but it this specific case the project is cobbled together in such a way that many of the paths were disrupted when I moved the index.php file into public_html. So the best solution in this case is to keep the project together in its current configuration