# Can you continue to match htaccess patterns after 301 redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My .htaccess file in my public_html has:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^testfolder/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ testfolder/$1
```

According to http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ which I am using to test output

when I enter http://www.mydomain.com/testfolder/aaa/bbb I get:

```
This rule was met, the new url is http://www.mydomain.com/aaa/bbb
Test are stopped, because of the R in your RewriteRule options. A redirect will be made with status code 301
```

Is there a way to perform the 301 redirect to make the url in the browser bar 'prettier'
while continuing to attempt to match patterns further down in the htacess file?

I have my codeigniter project in www.mydomain.com/testfolder. My first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^testfolder/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

is to rewrite any navbar requests for a contoller which come in the form :        www.mydomain.com/testfolder/controller/method to 
www.mydomain.com/testfolder/controller/method. The second ruleis so that anyone www.mydomain.com/controller/method will use it turned internally into www.mydomain.com/testfolder/controller/method

Thank you in advance,

Bill

Addendum - my current .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+b1/(.*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /b1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: don't use R=301, they are cached on the client browser over which you have no control. Use just R (default is 302)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Once the client has been redirected a new request occurs and rewriting begins anew with the new URL.

Comment: so does the .htaccess file get started over again after the rewrite?

Comment: Assuming the URL still leads to it, sure.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your rules are flawed and will definitely cause **infinite loop**.

Reason being that 1st rule is externally redirecting `/testfolder/aaa/bbb` to `/aaa/bbb`.

Now after redirect 2nd rule will also kick in since you're just matching `.*` there and that will be *internally forwarded* to `/testfolder/aaa/bbb/` and that rule will cause 1st rule to kick in once again and this will cause infinite loop.

Don't know your intent but you can use this code to avoid looping:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+b1/([^\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /b1/$1 [L,P]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: I tried this but  the browser bar URL produced by the navbar requests is not being rewritten from /testfolder/aaa/bbb to /aaa/bbb. I've added some more details

Comment: Replace `/aaa/bbb` with '/controller/method` and this should still work. However you should post your latest full .htacess in your question so that I can investigate further.

Comment: I've added an addendum with the current htacess. also for more of an explanation to what I'm trying to do please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16875945/can-2-htaccess-files-block-url-rewriting. Thanks - Bill

Comment: Most likely it is CI framework that is doing its own internal redirections. I am doing an edit see if that work for you.

Comment: "Most likely it is CI framework that is doing its own internal redirections." - I looked through the project for other htaccess files. Under application/cache/.htacess with 1 line "deny from all" Does that help?